# how to generate student attendance percentage per course, when they have specific day in a week

Tags: mysql, sql, date-range

[image]hi guys i really newbie in sql, i need help to generate percentage of attendance, here is the table:

```
Table Schedule

Schedule_ID   Course_ID Lecture_ID  Start_Date  End_Date         Course_Days
1               1          11       2019-09-09  2019-12-08      2,4,6
2               3          4        2019-09-09  2019-12-08      3,4
3               4          13       2019-09-09  2019-12-08      2,5
4               5          28       2019-09-09  2019-12-08      3
5               2          56       2020-01-27  2020-04-26      2,4
6               7          1        2020-01-27  2020-04-26      4,5
7               1          11       2020-01-27  2020-04-26      2,4,6
8               7          22       2020-01-27  2020-04-26      2,3
9               8          56       2020-01-27  2020-04-26      5
10              3          37       2020-01-27  2020-04-26      5,6
```

Reference of days of week used in this data.
1: Sunday, 2:Monday, 3:Tuesday, 4:Wednesday, 5:Thursday, 6:Friday, 7:Saturday

```
Table course_attendance
ID  STUDENT_ID  SCHEDULE_ID ATTEND_DT
1       1          2    2019-09-10
2       1          2    2019-09-11
3       1          2    2019-09-17
4       1          2    2019-09-18
......
46      2          1    2019-12-02
47      2          1    2019-09-11
48      2          1    2019-09-18
49      2          1    2019-09-25
50      2          1    2019-10-09
51      2          1    2019-10-16
....
111     6          1    2019-09-23
112     6          1    2019-09-30
113     6          1    2019-10-07
114     6          1    2019-10-14


table student
ID  NAME        
1   Jonny   
2   Cecilia     
3   Frank       
4   Jones       
5   Don     
6   Harry
```

i need to show up like this :

```
STUDENT_ID  NAME       Course_ID  Attendance rate
1          Jonny        1            82%
2          Cecilia      1            30%
3          Frank        3            100%
4          Jones        2            100%
5          Don          2            25%
6          Harry        4            40%
```

- EDIT this my last step to get percentage:

result:

[image]

```
with main as (
select ca.STUDENT_ID,
    ca.SCHEDULE_ID,
    s.COURSE_ID,
    co.NAME as course_name,
    st.NAME,
    count(ca.ID) as total_attendance,
    ((CHAR_LENGTH(s.COURSE_DAYS) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(s.COURSE_DAYS , ',', '')) + 1) * 13) as attendance_needed
from univ.course_attendance ca 
    left join univ.schedule s on ca.SCHEDULE_ID = s.ID
     left join univ.student st on ca.SCHEDULE_ID = st.ID 
     left join univ.course co  on ca.SCHEDULE_ID  = co.ID 
group by ca.STUDENT_ID, ca.SCHEDULE_ID
)
select *,total_attendance/attendance_needed as attendance_percentage
from main
order by 1,2;
```

Comment: Provide your sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts (of course decrease the amount of rows). Provide desired output for this data strictly, not "like". Add detailed explanations.

Comment: Please consider _normalizing_ the `Course_Days` column.  Do _not_ store CSV in your tables like this.

Comment: nope i dont store csv in my table, i just create on this thread for better understanding

Comment: Might I kindly suggest using  tab keys instead of irregular number of spaces in the future? I have to go through a lot of trouble substituting them with tabs in order to load the data into the tables, which is a bit painful >,<

Answer (score 1):

This can be done following three steps.
Step 1: Calculate the total number of days a particular course of a schedule has. It's a good thing the start_date is always on Monday and the end_date is always on Sunday, which makes the week complete and saves some trouble. By calculating the total number of weeks a course go through and the number of days a week has for that course, we can get the total number of days a particular course of a schedule has.

Step 2:Calculate the total number of days a student for a schedule. This is done fairly easily. Note: As the majority part of the table has been skipped and the OP has yet to provide the complete data set, I could only have 14 existing rows provided.

Step 3: Calculate the percentage for the attendance using the result from the above two steps and get other required columns.
Here is the complete statement I wrote and tested in workbench:

```
select t2.student_id as student_id,`name`,course_id, (t2.total_attendance/t1.total_course_days)*100 as attendance_rate
    from (select schedule_id,course_id,
        length(replace(course_days,',',''))*(week(end_date)-week(start_date)) as total_course_days 
        from Schedule) t1
    JOIN
        (select count(attend_dt) as total_attendance,student_id,schedule_id 
        from course_attendance group by student_id, schedule_id) t2
    ON t1.schedule_id=t2.schedule_id
    JOIN
        student s 
    ON t2.student_id=s.id;
```

Here is the result set ( the attendance_rate is not nice due to the abridged course_attendance table):

student_id, name, course_id, attendance_rate

2, Cecilia, 1, 15.3846

6, Harry, 1, 10.2564

1, Jonny, 3, 15.3846

Comment: thanks mate i apperciate that, it's simillar from your syntax, from that, answer, how to i get filter by people who less than 80% attendace?

Comment: Use a WHERE clause. i.e WHERE (t2.total_attendance/t1.total_course_days)*100<80